# Nginx conf changes doesnt apply

Tags: 12.04, nginx

I am using Nginx 1.8.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 with multiples domains, right now all my websites are online and working but I would like to change the port and others things in the conf of each domain (inside /etc/nginx/sites-available/domane).

The strange thing is : If i stop nginx : the wesbites are offline, which is normal. If i have a syntax error in some conf file : nginx warn me and wont restart, which is normal too.

But every changes i make doesnt seem to apply, like I can change the listen port to 1234 (or whatever), reload/restart nginx, the website still online. I can remove the domain in sites-enabled, reload/restart nginx, the website still online.

I use nginx for more than 5 years and its the first time I see that. Is there any cache or something new in the nginx configuration that i could have missed ?

Answer (score 2):

I know I am late to the party, but for those who find this through google: 
Try launching the url from a different browser ;)

Explanation: If you set a bogus redirect rule in a config with a `permanent` switch, most browsers will remember this rule and cache it. For example chrome caches it in some internal file that can not be cleared by removing cookies and site data - you have to actually clear full browser history and all browsing data for the last x hours.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your configuration with

```
sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Usually that file includes

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

And `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` are symlinks to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/*`, so edit the actual files, and check the config before reloading.

Comment: Already did, i have no error at all and the change doesnt apply, that is my problem.

Comment: The only 2 things that i can think of, is starting nginx directly and make sure you are using the correct config file with `sudo nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, and test the website with curl to see if there's any proxy cache.